# SQL/Laravel - Why does my query returns an empty collection?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

My Laravel Query Builder returns an empty collection, while the SQL string itself returns the correct records when executed inside phpmyadmin.

This is my code:

```
$times = Time::join(\DB::raw('(SELECT `ath_id`, `stroke_id`, MIN(time) AS time FROM times GROUP BY ath_id, stroke_id) b'), function($join) {
                 $join->on('times.ath_id', '=', 'b.ath_id')
                      ->where('times.stroke_id', '=', 'b.stroke_id')
                      ->where('times.time', '=', 'b.time');
             })
             ->where('times.ath_id', '=', $id)
             ->orderBy('times.stroke_id', 'ASC')
             ->orderBy('times.date', 'DESC');
dd($times->get());
```

Below is the sql that works inside phpmyadmin, but not with the laravel query builder. Also, this is the returned SQL string when using `dd($times->toSql());` (where `$times->getBindings()` returns `['b.stroke_id', 'b.time', '4298584']` to fill in the question marks `?`)

```
SELECT * FROM `times`
INNER JOIN (SELECT `ath_id`, `stroke_id`, MIN(time) AS time
            FROM times GROUP BY ath_id, stroke_id) b
ON `times`.`ath_id` = `b`.`ath_id`
    ADN `times`.`stroke_id` = b.stroke_id -- ?
    AND `times`.`time` = b.time -- ?
WHERE `times`.`ath_id` = 4298584 -- ?
ORDER BY `times`.`stroke_id` asc, `times`.`date` desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's something a bit "tricky". The query you are executing in phpmyadmin is, indeed, correct. However, Laravel uses `where()` and `on()` differently.

Use `where()` with a value and `on()` when working with columns.

```
$times = Time::join(\DB::raw('(SELECT `ath_id`, `stroke_id`, MIN(time) AS time FROM times GROUP BY ath_id, stroke_id) b'), function($join) {
                 $join->on('times.ath_id', '=', 'b.ath_id')
                      ->on('times.stroke_id', '=', 'b.stroke_id')
                      ->on('times.time', '=', 'b.time');
             })
             ->where('times.ath_id', '=', $id)
             ->orderBy('times.stroke_id', 'ASC')
             ->orderBy('times.date', 'DESC');
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries, section (CTRL+F): **Advanced joins**

> If you would like to use a "where" style clause on your joins, you may use the `where` and `orWhere` methods on a join. Instead of comparing two columns, these methods will compare the column against a value.

To make a bit clearer:

```
$join->on('times.ath_id', '=', 'b.auth_id')->where('times.stroke_id', '=','b.stroke_id');
```

results in:

```
JOIN on `times`.`ath_id` = `b`.`auth_id` WHERE `times`.`stroke_id` = 'b.stroke_id' -- AS STRING
```

The confusion came when `toSql()` returned your query and you assumed that `Laravel` knows that:

```
['b.stroke_id', 'b.time', '4298584']
```

the first two bind bindings are columns. But `where()` thinks that they just strings.

Comment: This explains everything! It did confuse me indeed. I think I read [that page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) completely. But this wasn't clear to me.

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman Once I spent a day trying to figure what was wrong with my query. Had the same problem: executing it in phpmyadmin gives me exactly what I want, however I get an empty result in Laravel...

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I would like to know which PHP platform to use for a site that offers services and connects people . . .

Comment: Ok great here it is : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151349/best-php-platform-for-a-site-x