# Laravel Query builder not fetch any response but same query work fine in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am trying to Run This Query from laravel Query Builder But it returns an empty response 
but when I get the query from the query log and run this in phpMyadmin it response with data.

```
 Project::join('project_assignation','projects.id','project_assignation.project_id')
        ->join('users','project_assignation.employee_id', 'users.id')
         ->join('eods', 'eods.user_id', 'users.id')
         ->select('projects.project_name', DB::Raw('SUM(eods.today_hours) as pr_time'))
         ->where('users.id', 210)
         ->whereMonth('eods.date', 9)
         ->whereYear('eods.date', 2019)
         ->where('eods.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
         ->groupBy('projects.project_name')
         ->orderBy('projects.project_name')
         ->get();
```

Query Log:

```
 Array (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [query] => select `projects`.`project_name`, SUM(eods.today_hours) as pr_time from `projects` inner join
 `project_assignation` on `projects`.`id` =
 `project_assignation`.`project_id` inner join `users` on
 `project_assignation`.`employee_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `eods`
 on `eods`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `users`.`id` = ? and
 month(`eods`.`date`) = ? and year(`eods`.`date`) = ? and
 `eods`.`project_id` = ? group by `projects`.`project_name` order by
 `projects`.`project_name` asc
             [bindings] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => 210
                     [1] => 9
                     [2] => 2019
                     [3] => projects.id
                 )

             [time] => 0.98
         )

 )
```

In php myadmin this query execute fine and also return related data.

[image]

Comment: Well, the query seems to work fine. You have two different months in the queries, so maybe there are just no results to return?

Comment: No, the first one is a month and second year.

Comment: No, I meant you're using `month(\`eads\`.\`date\`) = 7` in the phpmyadmin query, and `month(\`eads\`.\`date\`) = 9` in your Laravel query. Try using the same month in both queries so that it should return the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Laravel, the second/third parameter in a WHERE query is passed as a string, and would not be treated as a column name. Therefore, in a raw query,

```
 ->where('eods.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
```

would look like

```
 WHERE `eods`.`project_id` = 'projects.id'
```

You need to pass it in as a RAW query so that it would compare column to column

```
->whereRaw('eods.project_id = projects.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from first view I saw that in your SQL you didn't have comparison of "eods.project_id" with "project.id", which you had in Query Builder:

```
 ->where('eods.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
```

So I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796765/sql-laravel-why-does-my-query-returns-an-empty-collection#answer-44797660) can be useful for you

Comment: Actually, it is in the SQL, but you're right that this part of the query won't do what is expected.